# Python and Javascript differences on flattening a nested array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn js, but I know python. This code works in python:

```
def steamrollArray(arr):
    narr =[]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if type(arr[i]) is list:
            narr += steamrollArray(arr[i])
        else:
            narr.append(arr[i])
    return narr
```

However this similar code in javascript does not work

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  var narr = []
  for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])){ narr.concat(steamrollArray(arr[i]))}
    else{{narr.push(arr[i])}}
  }
  return narr
}
```

I'm trying to understand why this algorithm doesn't work in JS. Any help is appreciated.

edit: I'm aware of built in methods for flattening an array in JS. I'm trying to learn JS on FreeCodeCamp and so am trying different challenges. I'm not trying so much to learn how to flatten an array as much as learn why this code works in python but not in JS so that i can better understand JS.

Comment: Yours isn’t working because `concat` returns a new array, it doesn’t modify the original

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

because `Array.concat` method returns a new array but it do not modifies the original one. Check the example:

```js
var a = [];
a.concat(1);
console.log(a);
```

try this instead

```js
narr = narr.concat(streamrollArray(arr[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you have a built-in array method called flat(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat, try this:

```js
let arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
console.log(arr.flat(2))
```

Also you can use reduce() method and concat(), with an empty array as initial value:

```js
let arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
console.log(arr.reduce((acc, elem) => acc.concat(elem), []));
```